# Duplicate sources.list during apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-14.04, update

I wanted to install `PostGIS` on my server which already have a **PostgreSQL** installed. I followed this [PostGIS installation manual](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt).

I inputted this script:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

The console echoed `OK`. So I proceed to updating the sources list using `sudo apt-get update`. That is when a warning prompt caught my attention.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/apt.postgresql.org_pub_repos_apt_dists_trusty-pgdg_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/apt.postgresql.org_pub_repos_apt_dists_trusty-pgdg_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I opened `/etc/apt/sources.list` and check for duplicate `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main` but I only see one. How come it tells me there is duplicate?

Comment: Take a look at the files in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory. The duplicate may be in there.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Rerunning apt-get update, as recommended in the error, simply results in the same error. Checking the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list did show duplicates. Manually editing this file to remove duplicates fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this.
At first you should find the file which is including text "`wily-pgdg`"

It may be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` :

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wily-pgdg main

deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wily-pgdg main
```

It seems like there is the mistake. Making it look like:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wily-pgdg main

deb-src http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wily-pgdg main
```

worked for me.  (add the `-src`).